# android how to get current wallpaper name?

Tags: android

how to get the current `wallpaper` name i have search for it but nothing found . i just found current `wallpape`r but how to get current `wallpaper` name. here is the code where i get current `wallpaper`. help me with some code how can get its name.thanks in advance.

```
 final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    final Drawable wal = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
                    WallpaperInfo wallpaperInfo =  wallpaperManager.getWallpaperInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code for that if it helps you,

```
  PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  WallpaperInfo wallpaperInfo =  wallpaperManager.getWallpaperInfo();
  String wpName = wallpaperInfo.loadLabel(pm);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: String wpName = (String) wallpaperInfo.loadLabel(pm);

Comment: helo @vickyexpert r u there??